# Cookies in mvc 5

Tags: cookies, asp.net-mvc-5, shopping-cart

I am new to asp.net mvc. Cookies is better than session. But how to combine cookies with database to store cart in eCommerce site? Any reference link with sample code would be great help.

Comment: You might get some reference from below link
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/366143/storing-an-id-of-a-shopping-cart-in-a-cookie-for-unauthenticated-user

Comment: I was searching for combinations of cookies and database... It provide general idea only